# Xrandr doesn't detect HDMI port on the motherboard?

Tags: xorg, display, resolution, hdmi, port

I am running Mageia 4.14 KDE.

On a newly installed Mageia system I can't change the resolution for my monitors. I have One monitor hooked up to the HDMI port and other on VGA port. They both come up and display the same thing. However, their resolution is set so low that everything on the both screens look very big. So, I need to increase my resolution, but when I try to do that through system settings -> Display, all it says is **no primary output** and defaults monitor to choose from. The only resolution it has to select for default is 1024x768.

I ran xrandr on the console and I got the following.

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024x768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*
```

**lspci -v** command lists all the ports and buses information but it doesn't show or list anything related to HDMI.

When I try to change or force the resolution through Mageia Control Center by going to Hardware -> setup graphical server, the whole Mageia system become corrupted that it won't boot. Then, I had to re-install Mageia all over again.

Any hints or clues will be greatly appreciated.

edit1: lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 610 (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.    RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Serial controller: Oxford Semiconductor Ltd OXPCIe952 Dual 16C950 UART
```

edit2: Xorg.Conf

```
# File generated by XFdrake (rev 262502)

# **********************************************************************
# Refer to the xorg.conf man page for details about the format of
# this file.
# **********************************************************************

Section "ServerFlags"
   #DontZoom # disable <Ctrl><Alt><KP_+>/<KP_-> (resolution switching)
   AllowMouseOpenFail # allows the server to start up even if the mouse does not work
   Option "DontZap" "False" # disable <Ctrl><Alt><BS> (server abort)
EndSection

Section "Module"
   Load "v4l" # Video for Linux
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "monitor1"
   VendorName "Plug'n Play"

   # TV fullscreen mode or DVD fullscreen output.
   # 768x576 @ 79 Hz, 50 kHz hsync
   ModeLine "768x576"     50.00  768  832  846 1000   576  590  595  630

   # 768x576 @ 100 Hz, 61.6 kHz hsync
   ModeLine "768x576"     63.07  768  800  960 1024   576  578  590  616
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "device1"
   Driver "fbdev"
   Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "screen1"
   Device "device1"
   Monitor "monitor1"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier "layout1"
   Screen "screen1"
EndSection
```

Edit3: Xorg.0.log

```
[    16.097] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[    16.097] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    16.097] Build Operating System: Linux_4.4.88-server-1.mga5 Mageia
[    16.097] Current Operating System: Linux localhost 4.4.114-desktop-1.mga5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 31 19:24:17 UTC 2018 x86_64
[    16.097] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-desktop root=UUID=0b97d12b-f199-4b59-8dc4-ce6a5dca53e0 ro splash quiet noiswmd resume=UUID=31e45180-eec3-414f-a2cc-1f5a8ebbf50d
[    16.097] Build Date: 07 October 2017  07:33:00PM
[    16.097]  
[    16.097] Current version of pixman: 0.32.8
[    16.097]    Before reporting problems, check http://bugs.mageia.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    16.097] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    16.097] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Apr 13 09:43:58 2020
[    16.136] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    16.136] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    16.136] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    16.154] (==) ServerLayout "layout1"
[    16.154] (**) |-->Screen "screen1" (0)
[    16.154] (**) |   |-->Monitor "monitor1"
[    16.169] (**) |   |-->Device "device1"  
[    16.169] (**) Option "DontZap" "False"
[    16.169] (**) Option "AllowMouseOpenFail"
[    16.169] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    16.169] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    16.169] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    16.169] (==) FontPath set to:
catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d
[    16.169] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[    16.169] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    16.169] (II) Loader magic: 0x811d80
[    16.169] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    16.169]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    16.169]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[    16.169]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    16.169]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    16.169] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 953 does not belong to any known session
[    16.170] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:5902:1043:8694 rev 4, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    16.170] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    16.170] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    16.170] (II) LoadModule: "v4l"
[    16.207] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/v4l_drv.so
[    16.222] (II) Module v4l: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.222]    compiled for 1.16.1, module version = 0.1.1
[    16.222]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    16.222] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    16.222] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    16.331] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.331]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.331]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[    16.331] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    16.331] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    16.331] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    16.342] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.342]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.4.4
[    16.342]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    16.342]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    16.342] (II) v4l driver for Video4Linux
[    16.342] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    16.342] (++) using VT number 1

[    16.342] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for v4l
[    16.342] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    16.342] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    16.342] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    16.364] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.364]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    16.364]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    16.364] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[    16.364] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    16.364] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    16.364] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    16.364] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    16.364] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.364]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    16.364]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[    16.364] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    16.364] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    16.364] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen    section
"screen1" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    16.364] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    16.364] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    16.364] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    16.364] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    16.364] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
[    16.364] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 78.7 MHz, 59.9 kHz, 75.7 Hz
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   78.65  1024 1056 1184 1312  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (59.9 kHz b)
[    16.364] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    16.364] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    16.365] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    16.365] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    16.375] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.375]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.375]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    16.375] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    16.375] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    16.375] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    16.375] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    16.377] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.377]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.1.0
[    16.377]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    16.377] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    16.377] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[    16.388] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    16.388] (**) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    16.388] (==) RandR enabled
[    16.392] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    16.392] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    17.410] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    17.410] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[    18.053] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event5)
[    18.053] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall" 
[    18.053] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    18.053] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    18.069] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    18.078] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    18.078]    compiled for 1.16.2, module version = 2.9.1
[    18.078]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    18.078]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    18.078] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    18.078] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    18.078] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[    18.078] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    18.078] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    18.078] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.078] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7/event5"
[    18.078] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    18.078] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.078] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.078] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.078] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:rwin"
[    18.089] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[    18.089] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.089] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    18.089] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    18.089] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    18.089] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    18.089] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    18.089] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    18.089] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.089] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input6/event4"
[    18.089] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:rwin"
[    18.089] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    18.089] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.089] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    18.089] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[    18.089] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    18.089] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    18.089] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[    18.089] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[    18.089] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.089] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input5/event3"
[    18.089] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.089] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:rwin" 
[    18.090] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM) (/dev/input/event0)
[    18.090] (**) Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    18.090] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)'
[    18.090] (**) Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): always reports core events
[    18.090] (**) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    18.141] (--) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Vendor 0x45e Product 0x47
[    18.141] (--) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Found 9 mouse buttons
[    18.141] (--) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Found scroll wheel(s)
[    18.141] (--) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Found relative axes
[    18.141] (--) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Found x and y relative axes
[    18.141] (II) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Configuring as mouse
[    18.141] (II) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Adding scrollwheel support
[    18.141] (**) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    18.141] (**) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    18.141] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:045E:0047.0001/input/input2/event0"
[    18.141] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[    18.141] (II) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): initialized for relative axes.
[    18.141] (**) Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    18.141] (**) Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    18.141] (**) Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    18.141] (**) Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    18.141] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM) (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    18.141] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.141] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.141] (II) config/udev: Adding input device GASIA USB KB V11 (/dev/input/event1)
[    18.141] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.141] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    18.141] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'GASIA USB KB V11'
[    18.141] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: always reports core events
[    18.141] (**) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    18.141] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Vendor 0xe8f Product 0x22
[    18.141] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Found keys
[    18.141] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.141] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0E8F:0022.0002/input/input3/event1"
[    18.141] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "GASIA USB KB V11" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    18.141] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"  
[    18.141] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.141] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.141] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:rwin"
[    18.142] (II) config/udev: Adding input device GASIA USB KB V11 (/dev/input/event2)
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"  
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    18.142] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'GASIA USB KB V11'
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: always reports core events
[    18.142] (**) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    18.142] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Vendor 0xe8f Product 0x22
[    18.142] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Found 1 mouse buttons
[    18.142] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    18.142] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Found relative axes
[    18.142] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Forcing relative x/y axes to exist.
[    18.142] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Found absolute axes
[    18.142] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[    18.142] (--) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Found keys
[    18.142] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Configuring as mouse
[    18.142] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.142] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: Adding scrollwheel support
[    18.142] (**) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    18.142] (**) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    18.142] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:0E8F:0022.0003/input/input4/event2"
[    18.142] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "GASIA USB KB V11" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    18.142] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.142] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.142] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.142] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:rwin"
[    18.142] (II) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: initialized for relative axes.
[    18.142] (WW) evdev: GASIA USB KB V11: ignoring absolute axes.  
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    18.142] (**) GASIA USB KB V11: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    18.142] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller (/dev/input/event13)
[    18.142] (**) USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[    18.142] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller'
[    18.142] (**) USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: always reports core events
[    18.142] (**) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Device: "/dev/input/event13"
[    18.193] (--) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Vendor 0x457 Product 0x1139
[    18.193] (--) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Found absolute axes
[    18.193] (--) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Found x and y absolute axes
[    18.193] (--) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Found absolute touchscreen
[    18.193] (II) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: Configuring as touchscreen
[    18.193] (**) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5 
[    18.193] (**) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    18.193] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.7/1-6.7:1.0/0003:0457:1139.0004/input/input16/event13"
[    18.193] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 12)
[    18.193] (II) evdev: USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: initialized for absolute axes.
[    18.193] (**) USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1  
[    18.193] (**) USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    18.193] (**) USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    18.193] (**) USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    18.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    18.193] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.193] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    18.193] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.193] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event8)
[    18.193] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.193] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event9)
[    18.193] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.193] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event10)
[    18.194] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.194] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.194] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[    18.194] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.194] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.194] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    18.194] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    18.194] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    18.194] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Eee PC WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event12)
[    18.194] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    18.194] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    18.194] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Eee PC WMI hotkeys'
[    18.194] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[    18.194] (**) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event12"
[    18.194] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[    18.194] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[    18.194] (II) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[    18.194] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input15/event12"
[    18.194] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Eee PC WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    18.194] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    18.194] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    18.194] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    18.194] (**) Option "xkb_options" "compose:rwin"
[    18.195] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[    32.577] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[    32.600] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  4606.668] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[  4615.006] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Sorry if I misread your post but can you confirm that both monitors work - you get an output both to HDMI and VGA at the same time but nonetheless xrandr doesn't show HDMI?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I get an output both to HDMI and VGA at the same time. They are both displaying the same thing and at the same resolution 1024x768.

Comment: Hmm, are you using Nvidia perhaps? If not, what motherboard and GPU are you using? Can you post your Xorg.conf if you have it?

Comment: no video card at all... everything is onboard. Okay I will post xorg.conf... Unforunately, I can't edit my question.

Comment: Are you using a desktop PC with a motherboard of your choice or a laptop? It's possible you don't have a dedicated GPU but in that case your CPU might come with an integrated GPU

Comment: I have a desktop with two different monitors hooked up to it.

Comment: Someone else built this computer for me. I am not sure about GPU.

Comment: OK, I see. Post output of `lspci` - we need to know what GPU are you using.

Comment: okay... but how... I can't edit this question right now...

Comment: You can edit the question, pressing `Edit` button will take you here https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/579789/edit

Comment: I also added the Xorg.conf file.

Comment: This is your video card `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 610 (rev 04)`. I don't know how to solve your problem right away but knowing what GPU you're using might help you solve the problem on your own. Anyway, post output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and try to start X server without xorg.conf and check if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
[    16.364] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
```

You have an UEFI-based system. Instead of a traditional VESA SVGA, it provides a very simple framebuffer interface with very limited capabilities by default.

Since your GPU is a CPU-integrated Intel HD Graphics 610, you'll need to first make sure that the appropriate kernel drivers for it are loaded. The name of the driver module you'll need is `i915`, since that was the "grandfather" of Intel's CPU-integrated GPUs.

First, go to a package management utility and make sure the `x11-driver-video-intel` package (with all its dependencies) is installed.

To test the transition from the EFI framebuffer driver to `i915`, you'll need to stop the X11 GUI server completely and drop into text mode. Assuming that your Mageia Linux uses `systemd` (as quick Googling seems to indicate), you should achieve that in a temporary fashion with `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`. This command should automatically bring the system to a state corresponding to traditional SysVinit runlevel 3, i.e. a state suitable for multi-user servers that won't necessarily have a local display at all. The benefit of this approach is that if something goes wrong, you'll just need to reboot and everything will be back to normal.

Once in text mode, log in, become root and run `modprobe i915`. The screen may flash a bit, and the text mode display might now appear on one display only, with a different resolution. This is actually a good thing: it indicates the display driver can now handle two displays as different hardware entities. You can verify that the `i915` module is in use by `cat /proc/fb`: if it outputs something like `0 inteldrmfb` instead of `0 EFI VGA`, the `i915` module is in use.

If the system seems to crash at this point, you might try connecting to the system with SSH to see if just the display is inoperative, or just reboot the system to go back to where you started.

The next step would be to make the system load the `i915` module automatically at boot, and then adapt the X configuration to use it.

At this point, I would recommend configuring the system temporarily so that it will boot in text mode only. This will avoid the annoying problem of possibly getting stuck in a loop if the X configuration is not functional:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Then, add the `i915` module to the list of modules to be loaded automatically:

```
echo "i915" >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
```

Now, reboot. The system should come back up in a text-mode login prompt, automatically using the `i915` module. Login and become root.

If this step is successful, it's time to change the X configuration. The modern Xorg X server will autodetect common PC hardware pretty well, so I'm going to suggest that you simply rename your current `xorg.conf` file to e.g. `xorg.conf.old` and see how it's going to work without any configuration file at all.

Now, run `systemctl isolate graphical.target`. This should fire up the graphics mode again. Now it should be able to auto-detect the Intel iGPU and use a driver optimized for it, instead of the generic framebuffer driver. `xrandr` should have better results in detecting the various outputs, and the GUI display settings tools should also automatically detect the presence of two displays, although you might have to explicitly enable the second display for use.

If everything works, the only remaining step is to configure the system to boot in GUI mode again:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```